# Update multiple records using entity framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I wanna update multiple records by condition. For now i'm doing it like this:

```
var friends= db.Friends.Where(f=>idList.Contains(f.ID)).ToList();
friends.ForEach(a=>a.msgSentBy='1234');
db.SaveChanges();
```

But i don't want to get all matched data from database after that update all matched records, so is there any way to update records without TSQL and get all matched data?

Comment: you should use ``ExecuteSqlRaw`` and then get matched data.

Comment: Bulk update with EF is a frequently recurring topic on Stack Overflow. Please look for similar questions.